# Resolving "This website has been reported as unsafe" (Windows Defender SmartScreen)

Tags: blacklist, microsoft-edge

I had a website that was compromised—the attacker planted malware that caused a redirect to a malicious site. The security holes have now been fixed and the malware has been removed. However, Microsoft Edge is still showing the message "This website has been reported as unsafe", which was true a few days ago but is no longer the case. I can't find any information on what the process is to get this notice removed. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can't find any information on what the process is to get this notice removed.

Your site was clearly visible blocked by Windows Defender SmartScreen. Your problem is addressed in the [Windows Defender SmartScreen FAQ](https://feedback.smartscreen.microsoft.com/smartscreenfaq.aspx) or your might just have looked further into the *More Information* part of the message. To cite from the FAQ:

> Q. If I am a website owner, how do I correct a warning on my legitimate site?
>   A.
>   You can immediately **submit a request for a correction**. Windows Defender SmartScreen has a built-in, web-based feedback system in place to help customers and website owners report any potential false warnings as quickly as possible. In Windows Internet Explorer, from a red warning, **click More information then Report that this site contains no threats**. This will take you to a feedback page where you can indicate you are a site owner or representative. Follow the instructions and provide the information on this site to submit a site for review...

Answer (score 0):

In general I would say that these type of systems, systems that checks reputation of Hosts, IPs, Domains and so ons, have a delay on getting out from the black lists. So I suspect that your Windows Defender is checking a list (manage by Microsoft) where your host is still on it, not sure what is the process of remove the host of that list, but probably an email to them will help to speed up the process. Hope it helps